# Select columns together with the sum()

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a problem in getting the columns and I also want to get the sum of total_amount.

```
CREATE TABLE purchase (
    id int,
    sheet_number varchar(255), 
    total_amount decimal(23,6),
    transaction_status int
);

INSERT INTO purchase (id, sheet_number, total_amount, transaction_status)
VALUES (
    '1', 'PO10010000001', '120.18', 1,
    '2', 'PO10010000002', '87.23', 1,
    '3', 'PO10010000003', '53.56', 3,
    '4', 'PO10010000004', '150.28', 4,
    '5', 'PO10010000005', '160.53' 3,
);
```

I want to get the columns and also the sum of this total_amount with respect (group by) of transaction_status.

I've created a SQL query like this but it doesn't work with the expected one.

Here is the SQL query that I've made:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    sheet_number, 
    transaction_status, 
    sum(total_amount) AS total FROM purchase
GROUP BY transaction_status, id, sheet_number
```

I think the problem because I listed the other columns/attributes in the `GROUP BY` clause.

But I needed it because it will prompt an error message that the column is not valid since it is not contained in the group by clause.

The expected SQL query is like this (but I can't since there will be a prompt error):

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    sheet_number, 
    transaction_status, 
    sum(total_amount) AS total FROM purchase
GROUP BY transaction_status
```

The expected result will be:

```
[id],[sheet_number],[total],[transaction_status]

[1],[PO10010000001],[207.41],[1],
[2],[PO10010000002],[207.41],[1],
[3],[PO10010000003],[214.09‬],[3],
[4],[PO10010000004],[150.28],[4],
[5],[PO10010000005],[214.09‬],[3]
```

I just want to get all the same columns but I can get also the sum of `total_amount`.

Comment: I am not clear what output you are looking for can you add please.

Comment: Hi, @P.Salmon I update the post. Please check the added details. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window function :

```
SELECT p.id, p.sheet_number, p.transaction_status, 
       SUM(p.total_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY p.transaction_status) AS total 
FROM purchase p 
ORDER BY p.id;
```

Comment: This will produce the desired output if you add an order by id after from purchase.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the inner join to get the output as shown below.

Here I have taken total amount group by transaction status and done joining with actual table based on the transaction status column.

```
SELECT purchase.id
    ,purchase.sheet_number
    ,b.total AS total_amount
    ,purchase.transaction_status
FROM purchase
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT transaction_status
        ,SUM(total_amount) AS total
    FROM purchase
    GROUP BY transaction_status
    ) b ON purchase.transaction_status = b.transaction_status
```

Here is the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a1cfc057f80b0947fa0cd5a9e3368b6a) demo.